# the fibration in homotopy theory

Tags: notation, homotopy-theory, fibration

I would like to see why [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration) the  name "**fibration**" has been chosen. What precisely are the **fibres** (threads) in this definition? The name is standard, but I have never seen its origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fibration is a generalization of a [fiber bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) (as it says at the link in your post), where the intuition is clearer. There is even a helpful picture of a hairbrush on that wikipedia page, to aid one's intuition.

Comment: To which parts in the `hairbrush` correspond the names $X$, $E$ and $B$ form [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration) ? And the maps $h,p,\tilde{h}_0$ ?

Comment: The caption on that picture answers your questions regarding $X$, $E$ and $B$ precisely.

Comment: Regarding $h$ and $p$ and $\tilde h_0$, that seems to be a question for another post, namely the question of why every fiber bundle is a fibration, i.e. why a fibration is a generalization of a fiber bundle.

Comment: OK.I just do not follow what is the problem with taking $E=B\times F$ and $\pi$ the projection for the hairbrush. So why this is not globally possible.

Comment: It sounds like you have bunches of further questions about the mathematical meanings of fibrations and fiber bundles. That's great, however, in that case the proper thing to do is to post new questions, rather than asking further questions in the comments of the answer to this question (where no-one will see them but the poster and the answerer, i.e. you and me, and anyone else who perchance wanders by).

Comment: I've done it, please see: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4644935/fibrations-and-hairbrush-an-intuition).

Comment: Also, in the Wikipedia link you shared: Properties The fibers $p^{-1}(b)$over $b\in B$ are homotopy equivalent for each path component of $B$.